# Kendo grid column data binding

Tags: user-interface, data-binding, kendo-ui, grid

Can anyone show how to bind the below script into a column in the kendo grid using "kendo.template"?

```
<script id="edit" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <div data-bind="style: { color: 'red' }">
            Profit Information
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to bind it to a column ? any reason ? I will have a better option if you give a reason

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a grid, the you should not use `data-bind` since this is already bound to the model. You should directly use the HTML as:

```
<script id="edit" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <div style="color: red">
            Profit Information
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Ljsk8rk1/

Comment: Hi @OnaBai I specifically want 'data-bind="style: { color: 'red' }"' because I have a custom binding written in knockout which I want to bind here. data-bind="style: { color: 'red' }" Is written there just for easy understanding. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Internally, expanding a template is a call that receives two arguments: the string that corresponds to the template and the data bound to the template. For the case of a Grid this is the row. So, data-bind is not applicable because the data is already bound and you can (should) use it directly without any other question. I still do not get why you want to use data-bound a style that actually is a constant. Bounding is for something that is variable, your style is a literal.

Comment: Thankx @OnaBai... For asking the question only I put the style thing... There is a different knockout binding coming up there :)